# Google App Engine - Error: Model constructor takes no positional arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following code to try to create a message with a default value:

```
MESSAGE_STORE = "messages"
def get_message_key(key_name=MESSAGE_STORE):
    return ndb.Key("Message", key_name)

def save_message(msg):
  message = Message(parent=get_message_key(MESSAGE_STORE), message=msg)
  message.put()

class Message(ndb.Model):
    message = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Message, self).__init__(self)
      self.message = kwargs.get('message', 'No Message')
```

I get the error ever time, though.  How can I call this properly, it works fine if I just have no constructor and call it with:

```
message = Message(parent=get_message_key(MESSAGE_STORE))
message.message = "Test Message"
```

What is with the error?

Comment: You aren't passing args and kwargs onto the super call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman isn't that better as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: I faced this problem because, my model name and view class name was same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for anyone looking, the * and ** arguments need to be understood for this.  This page helped:

http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

With that in mind, this seems to work properly:

```
MESSAGE_STORE = "messages"
def get_message_key(key_name=MESSAGE_STORE):
    return ndb.Key("Message", key_name)

def save_message(msg):
  message = Message(parent=get_message_key(MESSAGE_STORE), message=msg)
  message.put()

class Message(ndb.Model):
    message = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(Message, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.message = kwargs.get('message', 'No Message')
```

Comment: I have to ask why you are even attempting to set defaults for an entity in this way.  You a creating more code than is necessary which overcomplicates something very simple and intrinsic functionality of ndb.Model and properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should not override **__*init*__** like this, you will more than likely run into problems.  ndb.Model makes heavy use of metaclasses and there is little or no value in overriding init especially in this case.

If you want a default value then define the model as follows

```
class Message(ndb.Model):
    message = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, default="No Message")
```

As an aside you should consider making your two functions classmethods, that way you don't have remember to import the functions each time you want to fetch and save Messages.  That way you only need to import the model and then use `Message.save_message` etc..